# Grey Matcher to get text of multiple elements matches the same grey matcher

Tags: swift, earlgrey

I am new to this framework. Could you please help me to get the text of multiple elements matches the same matcher on UI.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Your question is very broad at the moment. Could you post some example code of what you have already tried to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text of the element using the following function

```
open class GreyElement {
    var text = ""
}

func grey_getText(_ elementCopy: GreyElement) -> GREYActionBlock {
    return GREYActionBlock.action(withName: "get text",
                              constraints: grey_respondsToSelector(#selector(getter: UILabel.text))) { element,
                                errorOrNil -> Bool in
                                let elementObject = element as? NSObject
                                let text = elementObject?.perform(#selector(getter: UILabel.text),
                                                                  with: nil)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String
                                elementCopy.text = text ?? ""
                                return true
    }
}
```

And then in your test code:

```
var label = GreyElement()

for i in 0..<100 {
    EarlGrey.selectElement(...).perform(grey_getText(text))
    XCTAssert(label.count > 10)
}
```

The XCTest version:

```
for element in app.staticText[...].allElementsBoundByIndex {
    XCTAssert(element.label.count > 10)
}
```

Comment: A custom matcher is precisely what you need for doing this. However, please make sure that the test is robust as text changing can lead to failures.